# Why is accreditation based on time as opposed to knowledge so universally (or is it)?

Tags: degree

I have never seen a degree program that is purely examination based. Even if class attendance is not required, as it is in some European university programs, the program is still structured around a semester’s pacing in which you would enroll at one point, study a syllabus over a certain period, and then conclude with some assignments or an exam.

In theory, I don’t see why someone who has a certain level of knowledge - for whatever reason, talent, personal study, work experience - should not be able to just sit an exam (or many) and prove a level of competence they have in something for a degree, at any time that exam is being offered.

As far as I know this is not an option anywhere and I am wondering if there is a deeper reason for this than just happenstance in that most universities just happen to offer courses structured in this way since it caters to most people’s needs.

Is there some principle by which degrees are designed, stating that it is not desirable to allow someone to obtain a degree just by demonstrating knowledge (and possibly work experience)?

Or is there a way to obtain a degree in that way?

Comment: Why do you suggest it is based on "time'. The examinations are important. But note that examinations are generally a partial solution for determining knowledge. Oral exams do a bit better than written ones, but few exams really cover everything. Instead an assumption is made that if you know "these things" then you probably know the rest. I assume you mean an accredited degree (otherwise I'll sell you a diploma). And accrediting agencies want more than the absolute minimum.

Comment: Note that many (most?) universities will let you "pass out" of some courses by examination. This is usually for lower level courses, but need not be. If you want credit in such a situation, talk to the department head who might arrange an exam.

Comment: Also related: [Why not offer credit by exam to students who have failed a course?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/173702/why-not-offer-credit-by-exam-to-students-who-have-failed-a-course)

Comment: For a U.S. perspective (so not European), my classes (both taken and taught) involved much more than the final exam. Even for mathematics, there were several major tests throughout the semester, some minor quizzes, and homework (which sometimes, especially for advanced courses, was the most significant part of the course in terms of time involved and learning). As for other subjects (which even in mathematics I still had to take as electives), course work/grades involved lab work, class presentations, numerous multi-page essays (i.e. term papers), field work, group projects, etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you take the idealistic point of view that getting the knowledge and work experience is equivalent to spending the time to get a degree, then why do you need a degree at all? In such an ideal world, that knowledge and work experience should then get you the same recognition and job offers as the actual degree.

And if you say that we are not living in an ideal world, then I agree with you. However, preparing and giving an exam takes time, so they tend to get scheduled at the end of each semester after the classes, when most people would want to take them. They are also known to be less than ideal as a tool for checking for knowledge, so they are often supplemented with things like homework assignments, which are again scheduled for the majority of people.

At least in the university systems I have been part of, this schedule is the only thing stopping you from obtaining a degree by taking all the exams in a row. And even with this schedule you could take all available classes each semester and possibly finish in a year or two. If you make a compelling point, even things like homework assignments or formal prerequisites could be (partially) dropped. Things like this happen all the time, e.g. in case of prolonged illnesses.

However that being said, also coming from practical experience in a non-ideal world, my faith in people who say "I already know all of this, let me pass with less work" is rather thin. A vast majority of them greatly overestimates their skills, while the few that truly know their stuff often have have no problem in just passing the classes according to schedule anyway.

Comment: There are some exceptions being made, but that is very rare indeed. Besides other things, being a student can be a relatively cushy position, so there's rarely a motivation to be done ASAP in the first place...